# Something's changed about user timelines

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, timeline

[Six to Eight](http://sixtoeightapp.com)'s user display has just broken, as the `/user/id/timeline` route seems to have started returning different data. Previously, `timeline_type` of entries in the `user_timelines` array used to be one of comment, askoranswered, badge, revision, or accepted. According to the documentation, it's now one of ...

> all, comments, posts, badges, revisions, or accepts

either I've gone insane, or this is a total behaviour change from just yesterday?

Comment: Confirmed: http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/askubuntu/users/5/timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes to the site display of a user's timeline percolated up to the API interface.

They've been decoupled, and things should be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix, Kevin. But, erm, could we perhaps get some regression testing run every time you push an update? I've had four or five of these panics caused by behaviour changes due to new code , and 1 star App Store reviews that might accrue during faults don't go away!